# Make Query Table error: "The value is not a Raster Layer"?

Tags: arcpy, error-000840, query-table

I'm pretty new in coding and I'm struggling with my MakeQueryTable_managment tool using arcpy. I'm trying to do a query Layer based on a Layer and a table I have both in my gdb.
I keep getting this message error no matter what I change :

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000793: Invalid data element type
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Layer.
Failed to execute (MakeQueryTable)
```

I don't understand why it's asking for a Raster Layer, as it can be a Table View too as far as I know. When I use the tool with the same Feature class and table in arcMap, it works without any problem and the Layer appears.
Here is the piece of code failing:

```
MyGDB = arcpy.env.workspace = mygdb.gdb
table_name = "myTable"
myLayer = str(MyGDB) + "myLayer"

arcpy.MakeQueryTable_management([myLayer,table_name],"QueryTable",\
"ADD_VIRTUAL_KEY_FIELD", "", "","myLayer.ID = " + table_name + ".ID" )
```

Can anyone give me a little trick to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our format.

Comment: What is `gdb` in line 3?  Is `"myLayer"` in line 5 correct or should it be `myLayer`?  Is this snippet testable on its own or is it part of a larger script it is relying on?

Comment: You have enclosed myLayer in quotes when it should not be in the list for the make query table tool. Also as @Midavalo says what is `gdb`? Concatenating like that may be missing out a \ after .gdb

Comment: Thank you MIdavalo and Hornbydd. I did the few corrections you mentioned me,and I could go further in the code but still, it doesn't work until the end. Apparently there is a problem in the line 6, showing me this message:
    ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
    ERROR 000152: Invalid input data